# Xamarin: get files from a folder that I have created in xamarin mobile project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I try to make a list of filename in a folder that I have created in my project Xamarin.Mobile, **the name of my folder is “Doc” and I want to read the files in it** like one PDF and a INI file.

**I already added those permissions but I’m not sure those are the right ones**:

[image]

My code:

```
string folderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "Doc");
            if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            {
                var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath);
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Yeah", file, "Ok");
                }
            }enter code here
```

And here is my project solution:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not trying to get assets but the doc folders... but thanks.

Comment: your screenshot has Assets highlighted so I assumed that's where your files are.  If not, then where are they?

Comment: never mind, I see you're using the "Doc" folder.  Try using just "Doc" for the folder path, that should be relative to the root path of your App

Comment: I added more informations hope that helps. thanks.

Comment: again, you can (I think) just use "Doc" for the folder path for files in your Android project.  For the files in your shared project, I don't know how or if they are even included in the final app bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the answer, I needed to add in the Assets folder my files and set following properties:

Right Click on the file > Properties > Build Action > AndroidAsset.

[image]

And I changed mi code like this to be able to read the file:

```
AssetManager assets = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets;

            string content;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("Settings.ini")))
            {
                content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                await DisplayAlert("Yeah", content, "Ok"); // the DisplayAlert was to see if it was really reading the file.
            }
```

Hope it helps peoples.

Comment: Please make your reply as answer, it is beneficial to others to find this answer, thanks.